# Simple - using String#scan to extract an email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I've got a string that contains:

```
@from = "John Doe <john.doe@daemon.co.uk>"
```

When I do:

```
@from.scan('/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i')
```

I get no results. I'm trying to extract the email address on it's own.

I tried removing the \b's but this did not work either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your expression works fine: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/srBMT8nF9q)

The problem is the quotes around your regular expression means that it is interpreted as a plain text string rather than a regular expression. Removing the quotes solves the problem: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Ns5sO)

```
@from = "John Doe <john.doe@daemon.co.uk>"
@from.scan(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i) { |x| puts x }
```

Output:

```
john.doe@daemon.co.uk
```

Comment: Regular expressions are defined between /'s, so if you put that inside string quotes ruby won't make it a regex and instead will just look for the plain text.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment, so I'll make this an answer:

For any future use, everyone should make one modification: Don't restrict the TLD length to 4. New TLDs are being introduced very rapidly, you should now use a regex like this:

```
@from.scan(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b/i)
```

All I did was remove the `4` at the end of the regex, which places a maximum length of 4 characters on the TLD. TLDs used to almost all be 2, 3, or 4 characters long (.com, .org, .info, etc.). But now, they are introducing tons of new ones (.auction, .software, .business, etc.)

So nobody should restrict TLD length anymore (although leaving a minimum of 2 chars is still good).

Answer (score 15):

For those who only need to deal with addresses like `"John Doe <john.doe@daemon.co.uk>"`, which may contain a display name.

Use the Ruby `Mail::Address` class.

```rb
require 'mail'
#=> true
a = Mail::Address.new("John Doe <john.doe@daemon.co.uk>")
#=> #<Mail::Address:70264542184500 Address: |John Doe <john.doe@daemon.co.uk>| >
a.address
#=> "john.doe@daemon.co.uk"
a.display_name
#=> "John Doe"
```

Comment: I've been using this recently but have stumbled across a bug where UTF8 characters appear to be unsupported: https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/1014...

Comment: It is now fixed. Open source FTW :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated with the Regexp from: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP would make a current (2022) version of this

```
@from.scan(/\b[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*\b/) # => ["john.doe@daemon.co.uk"]
```

This will also work fine for multiple emails in a string, i.e:

```
"some text with john.doe@daemon.co.uk and john.doe@daemon.com.".scan(/\b[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*\b/) # => ["john.doe@daemon.co.uk", "john.doe@daemon.com"]
```

I couldn't see an easy way to convert URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP from having a \A \z at the start and the end to using \b \b at the start and the end. That would have been preferable and future proofed.